# AS3 - how to best use variables to effect functionality on different frames

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm currently building a 50 button interactive display, it needs on a specific frame to log 3 button clicks then save a variable or something that 2 slides later will relay whether the user has chosen the correct 3 buttons. This warning is a simple movie clip. Below I listed the 2 frames that need to relate to each other. Please keep in mind I am fairly new to programming Flash and still struggle correct syntax and utilization.

I appreciate any or all input on how I can better accomplish this using Actionscript 3

The below is hiding 3 boxes that will surround the correct answer once clicked. The fl_check36 needs to somehow in the else section send a variable or something i can reference that would let me show the error box movie clip to the user. (I already have a reset button working for that page)

[Frame 36]

```
MDI_07_box_mc.visible = false;
MDI_08_box_mc.visible = false;
MDI_14_box_mc.visible = false;

// Boxes to be clicked
MDI_07_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToShow_14a);

function fl_ClickToShow_14a(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MDI_07_box_mc.visible = true;
}

MDI_08_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToShow_14b);

function fl_ClickToShow_14b(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MDI_08_box_mc.visible = true;
}

MDI_14_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToShow_14c);

function fl_ClickToShow_14c(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MDI_14_box_mc.visible = true;
}

// Check for boxes correct and go to next frame
MDI_18_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_check36);

function fl_check36(event:MouseEvent):void
{
if (MDI_14_box_mc.visible && MDI_08_box_mc.visible && MDI_07_box_mc.visible)
    gotoAndStop(37);
else 
    Feedback_07_Wrong_mc.visible = false;
}
```

This frame just needs to check if the user got the information correct on frame 36 and show or hide the Feedback based on that.

[Frame 38]

```
stop();

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler_2);

function fl_EnterFrameHandler_2(event:Event):void
{   
if (globalVar = 1)
Feedback_07_Wrong_mc.visible = true;
Feedback_07_Wrong_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

Reset_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,         fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_2);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you declare a variable on frame 36, you should already have access to it on frame 38 of the same timeline.

Comment: Why you don't use a single class for all the buttons? Programming for every single button is not really optimal...

Comment: I wonder why your `fl_EnterFrameHandler_2` is constantly making `Feedback_07_Wrong_mc` to play, each and every frame. Probably you should instead drop the listener from within itself.

Answer (score 0):

What @Karma said is true. When you declare any variable on frame 36, it is accessible to any other frames that preceed it. You can also do the same by creating another layer called "Variables" with no keyframes in between which stores all your variables. This way, you would have confidence that the variable is acceccible to all the keyframes of the other layer.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this helps clarify what I should attack first and gives me a good direction to look into. Very helpful